# complex numbers, complex roots of equation.

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

$z_1=a+bi$ , $a,b\in\Bbb R$, $b\neq 0$ is a complex root of the equation $z^2-2z+25=0$. Without evaluating the roots, answer the following questions:

i) show that $\overline{z_1}$, the conjugate of $z_1$, is also a root of $z^2-2z+25=0$.

ii) what is the value of $z_1 + \overline{z_1}$?

iii) what is the value of $z_1\cdot\overline{z_1}$?

iv)find the equation with roots $4z_1$ and $4\overline{z_1}$.
 Confusion has hit in maths homework, help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: In this forum it is customary to give your own thoughts and attempts in addition to a problem statement.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to know is when $z_1=a+bi$ then $\bar{z_1}=a-bi$ so ii) $z_1+\bar{z_1}=2a$ and iii)$z_1\bar{z_1}=a^2-b^2i^2=a^2+b^2$ 
Also something to know is that some complex number is 0 only when both real and imaginary part are 0. So in i) $f(z)=0\Leftrightarrow (a+bi)^2+2(a+bi)+25=0 \Leftrightarrow (a^2-b^2+2a+25)+(2ab+2b)i=0$. Now note that $f(\bar{z})=(a-bi)^2+2(a-bi)+25=(a^2-b^2+2a+25)+(-2ab-2b)i$ has the same real part as $f(z)$ and the negative of its imaginary part, but they were both 0 for $f(z)$ so $f(\bar{z})=0$ too.
For iv) you want $(z-4(a+bi))(z-4(a-bi))=z^2+z(-8a)+16(a^2+b^2)=0$.